# Loading a datePattern from application-properties file in Logback and Spring Boot

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

In my `logback-spring.xml` file, I have a defined a timestamp like so:

```xml
<timestamp key="date" datePattern="yyyyMMdd"/>
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to load this datePattern value from my `application-properties` file. I have defined a property `logging.date.format=yyyyMMdd` which I am using in other parts of the code and it would be really helpful if I could use this in my logback file as well so that I have to only make changes in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

I pass properties to logback in my application. In my webapp initializer obtain the LoggerContext and input the properties. I reset the context because I change some other settings, don't know if it is required.

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
jc.setContext(context);
context.reset();
context.putProperty("prop-name", "prop-value");
jc.doConfigure(config)
```

In logback file, you can then use the properties line any other

```
${prop-name}
```

Comment: Doing `datePattern=${date}` does not work for me. I added date to the MDC.

Comment: I think it should be set in LoggerContext, not MDC. Another approach could be based on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/logback#6-variable-substitution), setting the property as a system property and then reconfigure logback to read configuration again